# Create bean by calling another bean's method

Tags: java, spring, dictionary, set, javabeans

I am not familiar with Java or Spring. I have a bean injected which is a Map. I want to inject another bean which will be Set of all the keys in Map.

`

```
<util:map id="servers">
   <entry key="www.google.com" value="google" />
   <entry key="www.amazon.com" value="amazon" />
   <entry key="www.apple.com" value="apple" />
</util:map>
```

`

I want use this bean to create a Set by calling Map.keySet() method.
`

```
<bean id="serverHosts" >
    <value></value>
</bean>
```

`
How to I initialize this bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
<bean id="serverHosts" factory-method="keySet" factory-bean="servers" />
```